# How to get the ID codes from a FASTA file using R

Tags: r, sequence, bioinformatics, fasta

Having a fasta file containing sequences like these two showing below, I would like to take only the ID codes and store them into a new .txt file.

```
>sp|P01920|DQB1_HUMAN HLA class II histocompatibility antigen, DQ beta 1 chain OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=HLA-DQB1 PE=1 SV=2
MSWKKALRIPGGLRAATVTLMLAMLSTPVAEGRDSPEDFVYQFKAMCYFTNGTERVRYVT
RYIYNREEYARFDSDVEVYRAVTPLGPPDAEYWNSQKEVLERTRAELDTVCRHNYQLELR
TTLQRRVEPTVTISPSRTEALNHHNLLVCSVTDFYPAQIKVRWFRNDQEETTGVVSTPLI
RNGDWTFQILVMLEMTPQHGDVYTCHVEHPSLQNPITVEWRAQSESAQSKMLSGIGGFVL
GLIFLGLGLIIHHRSQKGLLH

>sp|P18440|ARY1_HUMAN Arylamine N-acetyltransferase 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=NAT1 PE=1 SV=2
MDIEAYLERIGYKKSRNKLDLETLTDILQHQIRAVPFENLNIHCGDAMDLGLEAIFDQVV
RRNRGGWCLQVNHLLYWALTTIGFETTMLGGYVYSTPAKKYSTGMIHLLLQVTIDGRNYI
VDAGFGRSYQMWQPLELISGKDQPQVPCVFRLTEENGFWYLDQIRREQYIPNEEFLHSDL
LEDSKYRKIYSFTLKPRTIEDFESMNTYLQTSPSSVFTSKSFCSLQTPDGVHCLVGFTLT
HRRFNYKDNTDLIEFKTLSEEEIEKVLKNIFNISLQRKLVPKHGDRFFTI
```

The new .txt file would have the ID codes

```
>P01920
>P18440
```

each one on a different row

Any experience on this?
Thank you

Comment: Btw it is not a valid fasta format, `>` should be at the beginning of each line.

Comment: The `>` were being interpreted by the markdown system.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr`. We can use a regular expression which looks for an alphanumeric string that is immediately preceeded by `sp|`. This is called lookbehind.

```
library(stringr)
con <- file("test.fasta")
data <- readLines(con = con)
close(con)
IDs <- str_extract(data,"(?<=sp\\|)[[:alnum:]]+")
IDs <- IDs[!is.na(IDs)]
IDs <- paste0(">",IDs)
write.table(data.frame(IDs),file="IDs.txt",row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your file looks like:

```
test = c(">sp|Q9DFI0|DMT3B_DANRE Doublesex- and mab-3-related transcription factor 3b (Fragment) OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=dmrt3b PE=3 SV=1", 
"MLSWLKGHKRYCRFKDCTCEKCILIIERQRV", ">sp|P83238|OSTCN_DANRE Osteocalcin (Fragment) OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=bglap PE=1 SV=1", 
"AGTAXGDLTPFQLESLREVCEVNLACEHMADTXGIVAAYTAYYGY", ">sp|Q9W7M8|TYB_DANRE Thymosin beta OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=tmsb PE=3 SV=3", 
"MADKPNMTEITSFDKTKLRKTETQEKNPLPTKETIEQERQGESTP")

writeLines(test,"./test.fasta")
```

You can do:

```
library(Biostrings)
fa = readAAStringSet("test.fasta")
want_names = sapply(strsplit(names(fa),"\\|"),"[[",2)
want_names
writeLines(want_names,"names.txt")
```

Or if you don't wanna install a package:

```
fa = readLines("test.fasta")
fa = fa[grepl(">",fa)]
want_names = sapply(strsplit(fa,"\\|"),"[[",2)
want_names
[1] "Q9DFI0" "P83238" "Q9W7M8"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in fasta header `>` is followed by *organism name*, which is followed by *gene name* separated  by `|` from the *organism name* and the rest of the string, you can find your gene ids this way:

```
fas <- readLines('fasta_file.txt')                  # read fasta file
fas <- fas[!grepl('^$', fas)]                       # rm empty lines
(ids <- gsub('^.+\\|(\\w+)\\|.*$', '>\\1', fas))    # extract IDs
#[1] ">P01920" ">P18440"                            # result
writeLines(ids, 'fasta_ids.txt')                    # write results
```

Comment: I would add a writeLines function in the end, don't you agree?